# My SMDK2416 (for s3c2416) kernel works on 64MRAM but crashed on 128M

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, ram

I'm currently working on embedded arm linux with smdk2416(s3c2416)

The kernel is working on the 64MRAM. Recently, I need to increase the  RAM from 64M to 128MB with 64MB on bank0 and 64MB on bank1.

```
bank0's physical address is at 0x30000000  
bank1's physical address is at 0x38000000
```

I have successfully mapped bank0 from 0x30000000 to 0xc0000000, and bank1 from 0x38000000 to 0xc4000000 in U-Boot.

I have tried a memory test on these addresses (both banks' physical and virtual addr) under U-Boot.

When I'm booting the linux kernel with bootarg memory tag `mem=128M`, and run a simple program which use memory beyond 64MB. Then the system crashed with the "kernel NULL pointer dereference" message.

I found there is a `CONFIG_DISCONTIGMEM` defined in `src/include/asm-arm/memory.h`, but when I look into "Kernel Features/Memory model" in `make menuconfig`, there is only "Flat Memory" option.

How and where should I modify the config/code to make the Linux kernel works on the full 128MB?

Comment: Welcome to [unix.se]. I think this question is sufficiently on-topic (we can help you with U-Boot and configuration options, though writing new C code is outside our normal activities), but I'm afraid it's a bit out of our usual expertise. If you don't get a response here, you could try asking for your question to be migrated to [electronics.se] or [so] (don't repost: reply to this comment and I can flag a moderator to have the question moved), but there too it would be borderline at best.

Comment: I think the ideal site for such questions would be the newly proposed [Embedded Programming and Design](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50195/embedded-programming-and-design?referrer=2lF5gAel4peFRGSmvGLajg2) site. Unfortunately, it'll be a while before the site has enough momentum to start. Nonetheless, since you're interested in this topic, consider joining the proposal.